# Задача на питоне на проверку строки

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая считывает через стандартный поток ввода два целых числа, разделенных пробелом.
В случае, если пользователь ввел неверные значения (не целые числа или в неправильном формате), то программа должна печатать в командную строку сообщение «Неправильный формат ввода» и завершать работу.
А в случае если все правильно вывеси'OK'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Это очень просто.

```py
try:
  a, b = map(int,input().split())
  print("OK")
except:
  print('Неправильный формат ввода.')
```

Здесь `except` отвечает за то, что если строка `a, b = map(int,input().split())` допускает ошибку, то напишет `Неправильный формат ввода` . А вот строка `try:` проверяет нету ли ошибки с этой строки.

Comment: Спасибо большое надо мне более глубже изучить в тему try и expect